# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
> "

This is the error I receive when I try to do a `$.each` to this JSON object :

```
{"type":"Anuncio","textos":["Probando esto","$ 20150515"],"submit":"codParameters?___DDSESSIONID\u003d14EA4721A904D6DD71591156996E29F7%3A%2FMobilTest"}
```

I have also tried to do the same with stringify, but I receive the same error:

```
{\"type\":\"Anuncio\",\"textos\":[\"Probando esto\",\"$ 20150515\"],\"submit\":\"codParameters?___DDSESSIONID\\u003d06CBEC9D1A53616EFF703A8C71FBC2B4%3A%2FMobilTest\"}"
```

If I remove parameters `___DDSESSIONID\\u003d06CBEC9D1A53616EFF703A8C71FBC2B4%3A%2FMobilTest` from the object the $.each works fine.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Please format your code, it's impossible to read it like this. You can use the `{}` text editor button, or indent every code line 4 spaces.

Answer (score 290):

The `in` operator only works on objects. You are using it on a string. Make sure your value is an object before you using `$.each`. In this specific case, you have to [**parse the JSON**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196):

```
$.each(JSON.parse(myData), ...);
```

Comment: Felix, before $.each I have JSON.parse , the error appears when in the key submit have the value -> "codParameters?___DDSESSIONID\u003d14EA4721A904D6DD71591156996E29F7%3A%2FMobilTest".

Comment: Please post your code, I can't repro the error you are describing: http://jsfiddle.net/5asbeatq/

Comment: Don't post an answer if it isn't one. [**Edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30269461/edit) and include the relevant code *in* the question.

Comment: wasted 2 hours, and finally got it working using `validator.showErrors(JSON.parse(data))` , thanks a lot sir..

Comment: I get this error for $.each("ul li",function(k,v){ ... });

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, You saved my lot's of time. After convert string to Array it's working fine.

Answer (score 33):

maybe you forget to add parameter dataType:'json' in your $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   url: url,
   data: { get_member: id },
   success: function( response ) 
   { 
     //some action here
   },
   error: function( error )
   {
     alert( error );
   }
});
```

Comment: That did it to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only **solution** that worked for me and `$.each` was definitely causing the error. so i used `for loop` and it's not throwing error anymore.

Example code

```
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://example.com/api',
            data: { get_param: 'value' },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                    console.log(data[i].NameGerman);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

this work for me

```
$.each(JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"))
```

`$.each` only works on objects . if your data is an array you can change it like this

```
 $data = (object)$array;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29989934)

Comment: This didn't work for me, in fact, it just made the .each loop not find anything.