# i keep getting an error Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' for my jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

i got an error Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length', i follow a tutorial on youtube everything is exactly the same but i got an error. and i cant find any solution for this please help

```
$(function(){

    var $orderz = $('#orders');

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'api/orders.json',
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(orders) {
            console.log('success',orders);
            $.each(orders, function(i, order) {
                $orderz.append('<li>my order</li>');
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

and this is the JSON file

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "nama":"alan",
        "umur":"14"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Mona",
        "umur":"12"
    },
]
```

Comment: You should share which line is throwing the error since it's not clear from your code.

Comment: Could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269461/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in

Comment: i tried to parse json JSON.parse like the on you give jeff then i get a different error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 102

Comment: sorry scrapped here is the complete error         jquery.js:534 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [
 {
  "id":"1",
  "nama":"alan",
  "umur":"14"
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Mona",
  "umur":"12"
 },
]
    at isArrayLike (jquery.js:534)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:365)
    at Object.success (index.html:73)
    at fire (jquery.js:3305)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3435)
    at done (jquery.js:9242)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9484)