# $.each() not working with json data in $.ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I seem to have a problem with json data displaying here.. $.each doesn't work. I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' . The code for jQuery and php is given below.Any help in helping me finding where i am going wrong is truly appreciated.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','#dispf',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var prjid=$(this).data('id');

        console.log("Here"+prjid);

        $.ajax({

    type:"post",

    url:"fetch_pdet.php",
    data:"p_id="+prjid,

    success:function(res){

        console.log(res); //This displays as json string 

        $.each(res,function(i,pdet){ // here the error occurs
        console.log(res.proj.title);
});
}
});});
});

php:
<?php
$pid=$_POST['p_id'];

$qry="SELECT * from stud_proj where proj_id=$pid";
$res=mysqli_query($link,$qry); 
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$cid=$row['categ_id'];


$qry1="SELECT * from categ where categ_id=$cid";
$res1=mysqli_query($link,$qry1);

mysqli_data_seek($res,0);

if($res && $res1){
    $pdet=array();
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $pdet['proj']=$row1;
    }

    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1))
    {
        $pdet['catg']=$row2;
    }
    //header('Content-type: text/json');
    echo json_encode($pdet);
?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to "length" here or "in". And where's the html for this?

Comment: That's the error i seem to get. The html is a form where i want to display the details .

Comment: You'll need to Google that error, since there are a lot of hits. One of which being this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/30269461/1415724

Comment: try setting `dataType:'json'`. You shouldn't see a string in that console log...should be array or object

Comment: tried that. Now i get this error: Details: parsererror
Error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. It is an array, not a string. Sorry for that.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what is actually returned in the response body. Then validate that on jsonlint.com

Comment: Ok i'll try that . Thanks for the responses so far :)

Comment: The json seems to be valid json. But i continue to get this error.

Comment: add `mysqli_error($link)` to the query, does it throw back any errors there as well?

Comment: No, there is no error in the query

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your JSON string to a javascript object to loop around it

```
$.each(JSON.parse(res),function(i,pdet){
...
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: no you don't if you set `dataType` as mentioned in comments