# How do I solve 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in' and get my data to show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, mongodb

When I make a ajax request to iterate over multiple arrays I get

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

```
 $.get(url).done(function(data){
 var data = JSON.stringify(data);
 var reviews = [];
 var output = '<div>';
 $.each( data, function( k, v ) {
 $.each( data[k].mealReviews, function( key, value ) {
    output += '<div class="row">';
    output += '<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/' + value.accountType +'.png" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
    output += '<p>By <a>'+ value.username +'</a> '+ value.reviewDate +'</p></div>';
    output += '<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"><div class="row">';
    output += '<h2>'+ value.rating +'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> '+ value.subject +'</h2>';
    output += '<p class="textFormat">'+ value.review +'</p></div></div>';
    output += '</div>';
});
});

 output += '</div>';
 reviews.push(output);
 $( '#mealDetails' ).append(output);
 });
```

Comment: The `in` operator only works on objects, your data is  a JSON string, i think you should be doing, `var data = JSON.parse(data);` before using `$.each(data...`

Comment: Googling your title gave me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269461/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in

Answer (score 0):

`var data = JSON.stringify(data);` is intended to turn an existing JSON *object* into a *string*. Once it's a string, you can only call string functions on it. You can't do anything you can do with a normal object. You're getting your error because you turned `data` into a string, and then tried to treat it like an object. It's also possible, since you used jQuery `$.get` that `data` was *already* a string, because you didn't specify JSON as the return dataType in the ajax call, and therefore the `stringify` function simply had no effect.

You should be able to change your code like this for it to work:

```
$.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
  var reviews = [];
  var output = '<div>';
  $.each( data, function( k, v ) {
  //...etc
```

The `getJSON` method downloads the data into JSON format automatically for you. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/