# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269529/1018804)

And I did this:

```
function countryPage() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&disablelimitreport=true&format=json&prop=text|langlinks&noimages=true&mobileformat=true&page="+ curTitle + "&callback=?",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: countryPageSuccess
  });
}

function countryPageSuccess(counterObject, data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {...
```

But if I then do as per that answer

```
 $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, item) {
```

I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Log `data` and take a look at what it contains, more than likely its already an object

Comment: @PatrickEvans ok but if I don't do `JSON.parse` I get the error in the question title and yes I confirm it is already an object

Comment: The 2nd argument to the `success` callback is the *textStatus*. it won't be JSON. The JSON response should already be deserialized in the `counterObject`

Comment: what do you mean is the textStatus? @Phil

Comment: Well then show the code that represents that error, the body of your question doesn't match your title

Comment: Also, concatenating a bunch of query parameters is a bad idea. Try using the `data` property, eg `data: { action: 'parse', disablelimitreport: 'true', ... }`

Comment: @rob.m like "200 Success" or "404 Not Found". You don't need to use `JSON.parse`, jQuery has already done that for you. Just use `$.each(counterObject, ...`

Comment: The data you are getting from the API is the first argument not the second (which you called data). Look at the [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) reference to see how the success callback is defined

Comment: @PatrickEvans pardon, corrected, had copied the already tried solution i got from the other SO answer

Comment: @Phil you mean simply `$.each(counterObject, function(i, item) {...` ? And where is `data`?

Comment: @Phil would you mind to elaborate it more into an answer please?

Comment: @rob.m you already have an answer below

Comment: to receive HTTP error code, see my answer below. thank you guys I'm slow in typing, after I've done code snippet I saw you already said the same as my answer. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already a JSON object. You cannot parse it again.

to receive HTTP error code, provide a error callback function next to `success`, showed my code below.

```js
function countryPage() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&disablelimitreport=true&format=json&prop=text|langlinks&noimages=true&mobileformat=true&page=1&callback=?",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: countryPageSuccess,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}

function countryPageSuccess(data, result) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
}

countryPage();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you remove the console log so that we have a complete answer with `$.each(data, function(i, item) {` even for future ref? Thanks

Comment: yes but we still have  `//$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i,` even if is commented could be confusing for any future user coming on here, should have `$.each(data, function(i, item) {`