# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried to solve this with the answers of other subjects, but I can't, I have the only one error in my browser console, however all works fine:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 
false
```

here my JS:

```
$("select[name=categoria]").change(function(){
    valorBuscar = $(this).val();
    mostrarDatos2(valorBuscar);
 });

}

function mostrarDatos2(valorBuscar){

  $.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/empresa/CategoriaC/mostrarCat",
    type: "POST",
    data: {categoria: valorBuscar},
    dataType:"json",

    success:function(response){
        filas = "";
        $.each(response.cat,function(key,item){ //<= here is the error
            filas+="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='check' 
            value="+item.correo+"></td><td>"+item.contacto+"<br 
            />"+item.correo+"<br />"+item.nombre_empresa+"</td></tr>";
           });
           $("#tbclientes tbody").html(filas);

         }
      });

   }
```

Comment: Probably *response.cat* is false

Comment: So which line causing this error? The syntax doesn't look valid so i'm surprised this works at all

Comment: if you have one error, then **everything** is **not** fine

Comment: Are you getting any stack trace with that error?

Comment: edited for mark the error line, and yes, all works fine xD, but i still get the error on load the page

Comment: try logging `response.cat` and see what you get for response

Comment: @Endless i get nothing with the log of response.cat, the error is displayed when loading the page, not when executing the function onChange, this is curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.each` must be used on an object only
check to see if it is an object first 
Similar Question: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269461/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in)

Edit: does the error on load go away if you put the whole thing inside an if() statement?

`if( typeof response.cat == "object" ){
   $.each(response.cat,function(key,item){
     ...
   }
 }`

Comment: Didn't DV but it's well justified. You should flag the post as duplicate instead of linking to another answer about this subject

Comment: I said it's similar, i didn't say it's duplicate and i don't have enough reputation to mark as duplicate because of all the DV's, thanks!

Comment: the other post still have not an clear answer, and i tryed the suggestion on that post, and stil have the error.

Comment: That's fine, you have a flagging option for duplicates. But if you don't believe this is duplicate, and only similar, then it's fine by me

Comment: Can you post your code Alvaro, Are you checking the value of `response.cat` 1st before `$.each` loop?

Comment: @NickTimmer i get nothing with the log of response.cat, the error is displayed when loading the page, not when executing the function onChange, this is curious.

Comment: you need to add an `if statement` not a log statement. i edited answer

Comment: @NickTimmer thank you so much! using the if statement the console is clear again!!

Comment: Cool. If anyone wants to mark this topic as duplicate feel free. like I said I don't have enough reputation to do so.