# JQUERY script error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce Currency Switcher on wordpress and are getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

It seems that the error is loacted in this snippet and specificly the IF-formula:

```
function woocs_redirect(currency) {
  if (!sumbit_currency_changing) {
    return;
  }

  //***
  var l = window.location.href;

  //for #id navigation     l = l.replace(/(#.+$)/gi, '');

  l = l.split('?');
  l = l[0];
  var string_of_get = '?';
  woocs_array_of_get.currency = currency;
  /*
l = l.replace(/(\?currency=[a-zA-Z]+)/g, '?');
l = l.replace(/(&currency=[a-zA-Z]+)/g, '');
     */
  if (Object.keys(woocs_array_of_get).length > 0) {
    jQuery.each(woocs_array_of_get, function(index, value) {
      string_of_get = string_of_get + "&" + index + "=" + value;
    });
  }
  window.location = l + string_of_get;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this, since this prevents other scripts from running? I did try to comment out the snippets, which removes the errors, but makes the plugin unusable.

Comment: The `in` operator doesn't appear in this code, so it's unlikely that this is the source of that error message.   Are the commented-out blocks your attempts to fix the problem, or is that what the code looked like originally?

Comment: (Hm, on second thought I may be wrong about that:  `jQuery.each`  uses `in` internally.  Where is `woocs_array_of_get` defined and what does it contain?)

Comment: No this is the original code, i haven't commented anything out.

The any reason i suspect this part to be the problems, is that i can remove it and the errors disappear. 

Chrome developer tools points to the jQuery.each.... line.

Comment: It is  woocs_array_of_get = jQuery.parseJSON(woocs_array_of_get);

Comment: define currency like woocs_array_of_get['currency'] = 'currency'; instead of woocs_array_of_get.currency = currency;

Comment: @ShitalMarakana that would make no difference (other than introducing the bug of setting the string "currency" to the key instead of the variable `currency` as intended).

Comment: @Norrehus I can't reproduce this myself but it does seem that that error can occur when trying to `$.each` over a string instead of an object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269461/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in   Doublecheck that that variable is an object and not an unparsed json string.