# trigger(liszt:updated) - Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

This error shows in console. I want an Autocomplete filter search that if i select a location, sublocations will show up

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in `<!DOCTYPE html>`

This is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#filter_sublocation > option[value!=""]').remove();
            $( "#filter_sublocation" ).trigger( "liszt:updated" );
            $('#filter_location').change(function() {
                var location = this.value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php? 
   option=com_dlahe&c=home&task=sublocation&location=' + location,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#filter_sublocation > option[value!=""]').remove();
                        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                            $('#filter_sublocation').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
                        });
                        $( "#filter_sublocation" ).trigger( "liszt:updated" );
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269461/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in)

Comment: @Jerold please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.   If this is still an unresolved issue by next JUGB Meetup, perhaps we can get the group to assist you in fixing this up.