# google earth engine: error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in table3

Tags: python, google-earth, google-earth-engine

I'm following the code at this [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/821c1e554cf91c5be96467a3e17f39f5) (also found below). My final task is convert raster image into vector data.

But When Executing the code following error is occurred:

`Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in table3`

I'm not quite sure about what is causing the issue here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var count = sorted.size(); 
print(count)

var ndwi1 = sorted.map(
 function(img) {
   var img1 = img.clip(table2)
   var ndwi = img1.normalizedDifference(['B3','B5']);
   var thres = ndwi.gt(0.15).rename('thres');
   var slop = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation.clip(table2));
   var slope1 = slop.lt(20).rename('slope1');
   var slope_m = slope1.updateMask(slope1);
   //var and1 = ee.Image.and(thres,shadow);

    var shadowMap=ee.Terrain.hillshade(elevation.clip(table2),   img.get('SUN_AZIMUTH'),img.get('SUN_ELEVATION'));
   var shadow = shadowMap.lt(255).rename('shadow');

   var evi1 = thres.expression('(thr>0) && (shd >0) && (slp>0)? 1 : 0' , 

   {
     'thr' : thres,
    'shd' : shadow,
     'slp' : slope1
   });

  var evi = evi1.clip(table2);
 var vectors = evi.addBands(evi).reduceToVectors({
reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
geometry: 'table3',
crs : evi.projection(),
scale: 1000, 

 }); 

   return vectors;
 })

Map.addLayer(ndwi1)
```

Comment: The link you shared seems to require some sort of whitelisting for the Google Earth Engine access. The error message you are displaying generally occurs when [the in operator was used to search in strings, or in numbers, or other primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/in_operator_no_object). I think you might found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269461/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in) useful to continue troubleshooting.

Comment: Taking what Daniel said, if you have issues with the Google Earth Engine access, you can use the [Google Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help) doc for reference

Comment: Why is it a string `'table3'`?